Python Cryptography modules
I've installed Cryptography with pip install cryptography, but when I try to use it I get the following error:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _rust: The specified procedure could not be found.

The below code is my project but it doesn't work because of the error mentioned before
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
def writeKey():
    key=Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.txt","wb") as keyFile:
        keyFile.write(key)
def loadKey():
    return open("key1.txt","rb")

def encrypt(filename,filecode,key):
    f=Fernet(key)
    with open(filename,"rb") as file:
        fileData=file.read()
    encrypted_data=f.encrypt(fileData)
    with open(filecode,"wb") as file:
        file.write(encrypt_data)

def decrypt(filecode,filedecode,key):
    f=Fernet(key)
    with open(filecode,"rb") as file:
        encryptedData=file.read()
    decryptedData=f.decrypt(encryptedData)
    with open(filedecode,"wb") as file:
        file.write(decryptedData)

writeKey()
key=loadKey()
filename="message.txt" 
filecode="message1.txt"
filedecode="message2.txt"
encrypt(filename,filecode,key)
decrypt(filecode,filedecode,key)


Please check whether you have rust installed and available in the path.
